# Get Active Workbook Using xlwings

Tags: python-2.7, xlwings

I am trying to gain access to the active Excel workbook I have open using xlwings. Now I can do this using file paths but is there any way to do this without using the file path?

For example I am currently using:

```
xlwings.Workbook(file_path)
```

But if I take out file_path it creates a new workbook.

Thanks in advance,

Max

Answer (score 2):

According to your syntax, you're using a pre-historic version of xlwings, I recommend you to upgrade to the latest version (`Book` instead of `Workbook`). Check out the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/syntax_overview.html#active-objects) for what you're looking for:

```
xlwings.books.active
```